# Spring batch use commit interval from my JobContext sometimes not working

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my job I have a BeforeJobListener where I get from a database query a list of commit-interval values for my steps.

I save this values in jobContext, and I have my steps config like this:

```
<batch:step id="myStep" allow-start-if-complete="true" next="myNextStep">
            <batch:tasklet task-executor="mytaskExecutor" throttle-limit="${system.jt.nuc.init.pool.size}">
                <batch:chunk 
                    commit-interval="#{jobExecutionContext['CI_myCommitIntervalValue']}" 
                    skip-policy="skipPolicyError" 
                    reader      ="xxxReader"
                    processor   ="xxxProcessor" 
                    writer      ="xxxWriter" >
                    <batch:listeners>
                        <batch:listener  ref="errorControlStepListener"/>
                    </batch:listeners>
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
```

I noticed this is not working sometimes.
Ex: myStep commit interval in database: 15000 (If I read 45k records, I will commit 3 times). Well, I can see that my Writer is executed a lot of times (by each one):

```
20230425 15:38:16.781 DEBUG  org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter [[ # # # # ]] - Executing batch with 1 items.
20230425 15:38:16.788 DEBUG  org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter [[ # # # # ]] - Executing batch with 1 items.
20230425 15:38:16.795 DEBUG  org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter [[ # # # # ]] - Executing batch with 1 items.
```

But sometimes, the write of each jdbcBatchItemWriter is exact my commit-interval.

In general, my Writers are builded this way (I guess error can be here, I tried adding synchronized to the write method but none changes):

```
@StepScope
@Component
public class xxxxWriter implements ItemWriter <List<MyDTO>>{

@Autowired
    @Qualifier("myDDBBWriter")
    private ItemWriter<MyDTO> myDDBBWriter;
    
@Override
    public void write(List<? extends List<MyDTO>> itemsList) throws Exception {
      myDDBBWriter.write(itemsList);
    }

}
```

I am using **spring-batch 3.0.4** at the moment.

I have 28 steps, all configured same ways. I rechecked the commit interval in the JobExecution was filled in the beforeJob Listener. My beans initialization is lazy.

How can I check real commit interval at runtime? There are a way to assure this commitInterval setting?

Sure this is related with multithread config, but I can't find why sometimes work and others not.

Comment: `How can I check real commit interval at runtime?`: you can debug the listener in which you set `jobExecutionContext['CI_myCommitIntervalValue']}`.

Comment: Yes, this value is correct in the jobContext, but my "inner writers" processed registers are different from mi commit-interval. Only when I am using multithread. I added synchronize to all my ItemWriter write() method too